# How to convert String to DateTime without time zone conversion?

Tags: apex, datetime

I have a requirement to convert string value to DateTime without converting it to time zone.
 Ex:

```
Datetime today = Datetime.now(); 
String myDate = today.format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
Datetime myDateTime = Datetime.valueOf(myDate);

System.debug('myDate:: '+myDate );  
System.debug('myDateTime:: '+myDateTime);
```

in the above example, if myDate is 2019-09-15 23:03:23 then myDateTime is appearing as 2019-09-15 17:33:23 by converting to different time zone.

I want to get same value for both myDate and myDateTime.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Datetime Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm) is actually confusing.

**Note:**

***valueOf***: Returns the datetime in GMT timezone
***valueOfGmt***: Returns the datetime *relative* to GMT timezone

So, change the code to below:

```
Datetime today = Datetime.now(); 
String myDate = today.format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
Datetime myDateTime = Datetime.valueOfGmt(myDate);

System.debug('myDate:: '+myDate );  
System.debug('myDateTime:: '+myDateTime);
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks